# How to Increment a value in an MS Word footer with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have got the below code for insert a customized footer in word document

```
Sub addfootaspage()
Dim i As Integer
k = 1
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "<a id=""page_" & k & """/>"
    End With
End Sub
```

But this code has inserted footer (`<a id="page_1"/>`) in  all the pages.

How Could i increment the value in each page. Such as `<a id="page_1"/>, <a id="page_2"/>...<a id="page_N"/>`

Answer (score 1):

IMO, a footer is supposed to be identical at every page, except you tell it to be different than the footers on earlier pages. Also, "intelligent" content like fields can alter at every page.

I suggest try adding a page number field and watch how this works. It should count up automatically.

I have recorded a macro with Word how to insert a page field in the footer. I get this:

```
' Select the footer
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Select

' Insert an field that shows the page number
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
    "PAGE  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True

' Leave footer (needs print layout)
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
```

This works in my Word... (2013) Like this, it counts up automatically in the footer.

Comment: Thank you. Its inserting Page numbers, already i have it to insert page numbers.

Comment: How can i find the footer page number ([0-9]+) and replace with <a id="page_\1"/> in word

Comment: I really believe that basically you cannot manually enter a different footer at every page. If you need to set a different footer on each page, then set section break at the end of every page. Then you will be able to go with your first code, as the incrementing `k` is visible on each footer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to increment k. Try this:

```
Sub addfootaspage()
  Dim i As Integer
  k = 1
  With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "<a id=""page_" & k & """/>"
    k = k + 1
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Its inserting the same value in all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a for loop

```
for k = 1 to docWord.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
     With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
         .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "<a id=""page_" & k & """/>"
     End With
next
```

Comment: its inserting the same value in all the pages.

Comment: other than the Question, i have one more doubt, how to find the page numbers and replace with some text in footer area?

Comment: Yes I can see that Word does not like things like this. Would of guessed that it would be easier. But I will keep looking to see what needs to be done

Comment: After looking around a bit. It seems that footers are designed to be the same on every page. So far my search has only shown that the first page footer can be different. So you cannot do what you are trying to do. You will have to look at doing it through something that is not MS Word. Or if you are then pulling this into somewhere else you will need to add the extra around it. But only thing a footer can do would be a standard 1,2,3,.... page count

Comment: Is it just to look like that? Or do you need it for some other purpose? as you can move a page count around in the footer manually. So you could just type "<a id=".... and then have a big space where the page number should be and then have the rest of your string